# Slack authorization "Post to" option set to only @slackbot

Tags: slack, slack-api

**Incoming webhook configurable Post to options**

[image: Screen Shot]

Hi, is there a way to customize the the `Post to` options in slack. I want the user to give only authorization to post to himself or @slackbot channel and not choose other option.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Since in general channels have different names on every Slack workspace it makes sense to let the user chose it on install. However, if you add a bit more information about the use case we can maybe find another solution to your problem.

Comment: Basically we need the user to be notified to particular private channel, or himself (@slackbot), based on user provided consent. We wanted to limit the users choice so that he does grant consent to post on any public channel. As the information may be spam to users on this public channel.  
I guess the other workaround is to have bot user installed and have the bot send the information to the desired channels.

Comment: you do not need a bot user for that. The standard user token will work if you include the required scopes.